# Possible null pointer dereference in SONAR

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have tried to point critical issues in Sonar with the following code:

```
if (candidate.isDirectory() && candidate.canRead() && 
          TEMPLATE.equalsIgnoreCase(candidate.getName())) {  
  List<String> fileContentList = Arrays.asList(candidate.list());
```

I have also done the change below, but it still didn't work

```
if(null != Arrays.asList(candidate.list())){
  List<String> fileContentList = Arrays.asList(candidate.list());}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you ensured that `candidate` is not null?

Comment: What type the variable `candidate` is? What does `candidate.list()` return?

Comment: You mean adding check as  if(null != candidate.list()){ List<String> fileContentList = Arrays.asList(candidate.list());}

Comment: Can you add a definition of `TEMPLATE` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occures because `candidate` can be null. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Null_Dereference for a description.

You could do sth. like this:

```
List<String> fileContentList = candidate != null ? Arrays.asList(candidate.list()) : new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hi , It dint not help me.

Comment: Hi , It dint not help me.
    if (candidate.isDirectory() && candidate.canRead() && "template".equalsIgnoreCase(candidate.getName())) {  
      List<? extends Object> fileContentList = candidate != null ? Arrays.asList(candidate.list()) : new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Sure. You have to check if candidate is null before anything else! You will have a NPE on `candidate.isDirectory()` in case candidate is null.

Comment: I added null check as below but again it dint help.
Let me know what wrong i am doing here.
    if (candidate != null && candidate.isDirectory() && candidate.canRead() && TEMPLATE.equalsIgnoreCase(candidate.getName())) {  
      List<String> fileContentList = Arrays.asList(candidate.list());}