# SonarQube shows Possible null pointer dereference

Tags: java, null, sonarqube, nullreferenceexception

Possible null pointer dereference error in this code:

```
if(!Util.isNull(dir)){
    if (dir.isDirectory()){
        if(!Util.isNull(dir.list()))
            if((!Util.isNull(dir.list().length))) // issue reported here
                if(dir.list().length == 0) // another issue reported here
                    if (dir.delete())
                        LOGGER.info("deleted:");
                    }
                }
```

How can I fix these issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible null pointer dereference in SONAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295215/possible-null-pointer-dereference-in-sonar)

Comment: Sonar knows about Util.isNull in other files in my application

Comment: Just to point out: assuming `dir` is a `File`, `dir.list().length` is never null, it's an `int`. Similarly, if `dir.isDirectory()`, then `dir.list()` isn't null.

Comment: I tried many consitions so ended up adding dir.list().length.Will remove it

Comment: @vk1 What is the version of SonarJava installed on your server ? What is the package name of the Util class ? what is the type of dir ? how is that value passed to this piece of code (is it a local var, a method parameter?) ? please provide all the relevant information for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 8):

You check, that `dir.list()` is not null. Afterwards you do other calls to `dir.list()`, and assume, that is cannot be null in this case.

SonarJava tries to tell you, that even though `dir.list()` has not been null in the first place, it could have turned null for the second/third call.

To solve this issue:

1. save the result of `dir.list()` in a variable
2. check that the variable is not null
3. use the variable

This is also know as the *extract variable* refactoring, and it has additional good effects. If you don't expect the result of `dir.list()` to change between calls, then you will improve the performance as well, since the program doesn't need to access the filesystem again to produce the content of the directory.

Comment: @vk1 Cool! Thanks for your feedback! Consider marking it as "accepted" (green tick icon). This will give you 2 reputation points (yeah) and me 15 reputation points (yeah!) and show all other readers right away, that this solved your problem. You could then even remove your comment (as it will be obsolete).

Comment: SonarQube should add this as sample code